# Web API throws exception after installing AttributeRouting

Tags: invalidoperationexception, attributerouting

I developed a simple VB .NET Web API project using .NET 4.5

This project was working perfectly fine, but I decided to install the [AttributeRouting](http://attributerouting.net/) nuget package. After installing this package every function seems to raise the following exception:

> The constraint entry 'inboundHttpMethod' on the route with route
>   template 'Company' must have a string value or be of a type which
>   implements 'IHttpRouteConstraint'.

In this message 'Company' is the route name to a simple GET method that simple returns one object. Every route results in this error message. The stacktrace is:

> [InvalidOperationException: The constraint entry 'inboundHttpMethod'
>   on the route with route template 'Company/{Id}' must have a string
>   value or be of a type which implements 'IHttpRouteConstraint'.]
>   System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpRoute.ProcessConstraint(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Object constraint, String parameterName,
>   HttpRouteValueDictionary values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)
>   +346    System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpRoute.ProcessConstraints(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpRouteValueDictionary values, HttpRouteDirection
>   routeDirection) +201
>   System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpRoute.GetRouteData(String virtualPathRoot,
>   HttpRequestMessage request) +430
>   AttributeRouting.Web.Http.Framework.HttpAttributeRoute.GetRouteData(String
>   virtualPathRoot, HttpRequestMessage request) +250
>   System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HttpWebRoute.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext) +191
>   System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext) +233
>   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase
>   context) +60
>   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +82
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +136    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69

I found the following thread which describes my problem: https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting/issues/191

Unfortunately, this fix does not seem to help: https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting/issues/191#issuecomment-13814025

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I definitely feel like this issue is related with in memory hosting and do have a solution in the [link](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting/issues/191#issuecomment-13814025) that you mention above. 
After updating to MVC 5 I came across this issue and following the workout in this [link](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting/issues/191#issuecomment-13814025) which ultimately helped me out.
Here is how I did it.

In global.ascx page, I have the following:

```
AttributeRoutingHttpConfig.RegisterRoutes(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes);
```

In `AttributeRoutingHttpConfig` class, I replaced the code

```
routes.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

with

```
routes.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(cfg =>
{
                cfg.InMemory = true;
                cfg.AutoGenerateRouteNames = true;
                cfg.AddRoutesFromAssemblyOf<Your_API_Controller>();
            });
```

You can overwrite Your_API_Controller with any of your ApiController class. (Yes, don't know why but any api controller you want works ;) )

Hope this helps,

Comment: That helped me thank you. Did you have to change this setting when your changed your hosting or pushed your application to production server?